# how to solve the problem "New unsatisfied dependencies found:/usr/bin/bustle-dbus-monitor" using the %filter_from_requires macro in specfile

Tags: macros, redhat, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am building an rpm package and when building I get the error "New unsatisfied dependencies found:/usr/bin/bustle-dbus-monitor" I am trying to solve it using the %filter_from_requires macro, but my knowledge is not enough to use it correctly, I do not know how to specify the correct arguments to this macro

Here is my attempt at using a macro
A line from my specfile
%filter_from_requires /usr/bin/bustle-dbus-monitor/d
But unfortunately I get this error
" /bin/sed: can't find a label to go to "in/bustle-dbus-monitor/d"

Please write how correctly should I write to spec
Preferably the line itself